# Upgrade Debian to unstable on VirtualBox: udev problem

Tags: virtualbox, debian, kernel, packages, udev

I'm running Debian stable on VirtualBox on Windows Vista 64-bit Ultimate.  It's been running great, but I needed some newer packages, so I put `sid` in my `sources.list` to upgrade to unstable (as I've done a dozen times on various Linux boxes over the years).

When I upgraded, something went screwy and it asked me to run `apt-get -f install` to fix them, which gave this:

```
(Reading database ... 77846 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace udev 0.125-7+lenny3 (using .../archives/udev_151-3_amd64.deb) ...


Since release 150, udev requires that support for the CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED
feature is disabled in the running kernel.

Please upgrade your kernel before or while upgrading udev.

AT YOUR OWN RISK, you can force the installation of this version of udev
WHICH DOES NOT WORK WITH YOUR RUNNING KERNEL AND WILL BREAK YOUR SYSTEM
AT THE NEXT REBOOT by creating the /etc/udev/kernel-upgrade file.
There is always a safer way to upgrade, do not try this unless you
understand what you are doing!


dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_151-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5) of script `vboxadd-x11' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 6) of script `vboxadd-x11' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5) of script `vboxadd-x11' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 6) of script `vboxadd-x11' overwrites defaults (empty).
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_151-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have the VirtualBox extensions installed, and it looks like the `udev` install doesn't know what to make of them.  But I don't know exactly where/how they're installed (I just ran the `VBoxLinuxAdditions-amd64.run` script, basically), so I don't know how to disable them.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you explicitly to upgrade your kernel, because udev clashes with the
`CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED` kernel configuration.

So you should update your kernel. I am pretty sure sid already comes with a `linux-image` package that has it disabled. Just install it and try to install udev again.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll see if I can find a `linux-image` that has that.  I had simply assumed `dist-upgrade` would take care of that sort of thing (as it always has in the past, for me).

Comment: And the Virtualbox "guest additions" are required (AFAICT) to run at higher resolutions, or in seamless mode, and are definitely required to mount shared folders (vboxfs).

Comment: @Ken: Right, I didn't think about these extra things. And for `dist-upgrade`, sometimes (rarely though) it needs some extra manual reordering of packages.